# What is the full name for the "ARD" of ARD kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

See below, my question is not technical, but just asking what is the full name for the "ARD" in ARD kernel.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Automatic Relevance Determination](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ard.html).

See also 
[Automatic relevance determination for least squares support vector machine regression](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/938745/?part=1), or 
[Automatic relevance determination for least squares support vector machine classifiers](https://www.elen.ucl.ac.be/Proceedings/esann/esannpdf/es2001-15.pdf).